# Custom referencable items

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate, itemize

I have a list of conditions I want to reference, so I use

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \item \label{foo} ...
   \item \label{bar} ...
\end{enumerate}
We reference the condition \ref{foo}.
```

This way the conditions are numbered 1, 2, 3…
But what if I want a custom “numbering” reflecting some relation between the conditions like 1, 1', 2, 3, …? If I write

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \item \label{foo} ...
   \item[1'] \label{bar} ...
\end{enumerate}
```

the referencing does not work, the value 1' is not associated with the label bar.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to associate a label to an `\item[]` since the relevant counter (`enumi` in this case) is not used at all -- `\item[]` is explicitly meant for using a different `item label` which is perhaps not generated by an enumeration. It could be a letter, another symbol or -- with some effort -- even graphics.

Redefinining `\item` is possible, but tedious.

The `crossreftools` package provides `\crtcrossreflabel{displayed label value}[labelname]` which can be inserted for this.

Please note that `\item[{\crtcrossreflabel{1'}[bar]}]` must be used, since an optional argument (the one from `\crtcrossreflabel`) appears in another optional argument (the one from `\item`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\begin{document}

See \ref{bar}

\begin{enumerate}
   \item \label{foo} ...
   \item[{\crtcrossreflabel{1'}[bar]}]  ...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]